# mvc.net redirecting form get to 'nice' url best approach

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, redirect, routes

I currently have a collection of routes like

{controller}/{action}/{from}/{to}/{some}/{other}/{things}
{controller}/{action}/{from}/{to}/{some}/{other}
{controller}/{action}/{from}/{to}
{controller}/{action}

and views with forms with get actions to retrieve the results. But the get actions go to the 
default/last route with the parameters in the query strings. What's the best approach to handle redirecting to the pretty-url for the most specific route? 
i.e. when the form submits goes to 
`myurl.com/controller/action?from=20091021&to=20091131`
its redirected to 
`myurl.com/controller/action/from-20091021/to-20091131`

Generally, I'm wondering if I'm just missing something fundamental about sensible route design, as I'm also having a little trouble with Html.RouteLink mapping to a route rather than the query string style urls.

Thanks in advance for any advice/ guidance/ useful links.

Answer (score 3):

A form is always going to encode the parameters as a query string.  If you want the client to issue a pretty url `GET`, then you'll want to go with a submit handler than constructs the URL on the client side.  If it's okay to have an extra round trip, then consider using a `POST` and have an action which takes the `POST` and reconstructs the url and does a RedirectToAction to an action that accepts the values via `GET`.

Client-side:

```
 $(function() {
     $('form').submit( function() {
         var params = [ $('from').val(), $('to').val(), ... ];
         location.href = $(this).attr('action') + '/' + params.join('/');
         return false;
     });
 $);
```

Server-side

```
 [AcceptVerbs( HttpVerbs.Post )]
 [ActionName( "MyAction" )]
 public ActionResult MyPostAction( string from, string to, ... )
 {
     // you may be able to simply reuse the RouteValueDictionary, but may
     // also need some transformations...
     return RedirectToAction( "MyAction", new { from = from, to = to, ... } );
 }

 [AcceptVerbs( HttpVerbs.Get )]
 public ActionResult MyAction( string from, string to, ... )
 {
     ...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Aha! I think I've found my problem with route-based stuff not returning the route I was expecting - I had specified defaults for too many of the routes, and this then meant the default (last) route was always matching - and every parameter ended up in the querystring.